# Parameter count mismatch thrown when reflecting string

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a generic method that works for most of my custom types.  Today I'm building up unit tests.  The extension fails with a type `string`.  string comes up with two public instance properties, `Length` and `Chars`.  When I call `GetValue` it bombs out "parameter count mismatch".

I don't have any need to allow a string.  Can I add a constraint to my generic sufficient enough to solve the problem?

Code snippet

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> items){...

    //List<T> generally works...just found it failing out with string
    List<string> items = new List<string> { "cookie", "apple", "whatever" };
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(string).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[props.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747572/how-do-i-deal-with-arrays-using-reflection

Comment: @ChrisShain - I don't follow.  They are talking about arrays.  According to MSDN List<T> is not an Array.  What am I supposed to get from that link?

Comment: The Chars property is the indexer, you can't pass null as the 2nd argument.  I very seriously doubt you want to see this property.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Chars` is an *indexer* in C# terminology - but a "property with index parameters" in .NET/CLR terminology... so you can *only* get the value by specifying arguments. So in this case, it's representing the indexer used here:

```
char c = text[3];
```

In a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` the indexer would be the way you'd get `dictionary[key]`.

If you only want "normal" properties, filter the list of properties by the ones where [PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters.aspx) returns an empty array.

Comment: Ok, you've helped me way too much.  I have to buy your book.  Just one question before I do, are you gonna release a new edition in the next 30 days?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Nope - not planning on doing a new version for a long time. I'll write a (free) extra chapter for C# 5. I have two other books I want to start writing in the next year or two...